# Click on drop down in cordova android

Tags: cordova, select, dropdown

I'm trying to click on select tag/Drop down in Cordova android. I've tried same in web app by using bellow code

```
var myDropDown=$("[id$='drop_down_id']");
var length = $("[id$='drop_down_id']> option").length;
//Open dropdown
myDropDown.attr('size',length);
```

With the help of this code i'm able to open the drop down. Same code I've tried in Cordova but i'm unable to open the drop down. My app's Drop downs are looks like (In both android and web)

**Android**

[image]

**Web**

[image]

To achieve this i've tried these also

```
jQuery('#drop_down_id').click();

document.getElementById("drop_down_id").click();

$("#drop_down_id").click();

$("#drop_down_id").trigger('click');
```

Anyone know how to trigger select tag/drop down in Cordova android

Comment: Try this `$("#drop_down_id").focus();`

Comment: In this way also it's not opening

Answer (score 0):

Try using this meta tag for the `Content-Security-Policy` in `index.html`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="connect-src *; default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' gap: data: ms-appdata: blob: file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />
```

`$('#drop_down_id').click();` should work just fine.